# I have installed eslint on vite VueJS3 getting errors: The keyword 'interface' is undefined

Tags: eslint, vuejs3, vite

On a project that compiled before I installed esLint I get errors.

It complains about **Parsing error: The keyword 'interface' is reserved** for a file that contains no such keyword. I moved the interface definitions to my common **types.d.ts**.

I don't know which configuration files will help you diagnose this, please ask if you know.

Comment: It seems to me it is processing typescript as if it is javascript

Comment: If I eliminate the eslintPlugin() from vite.config.js, everything compiles and runs just fine, but then I'm probably not actually using eslint.